# Unable to get callback from function

Tags: node.js

Trying to get the variable `random_song` from the function `functions.random_song`

Function:

```
functions.random_song = () => {
  fs.readFile('auto_playlist.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`${`ERR`.red} || ${`Error fetching song from auto playlist ${err}`.red}`);
    }
    let songs = data.split('\n');
    songs.splice(-1, 1);
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*songs.length);
    let random_song = (songs[random]);
    return random_song;
  })
}
```

Attempting to callback the random song

```
functions.random_song(song => { 
console.log(song)
})
```

The code just return `undefined` Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
functions.random_song = (callback) => {
  fs.readFile('auto_playlist.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // Do stuff
      return callback(err);
    }
    // Do stuff
    callback(null, random_song);
  })
}
```

And then call it:

```
functions.random_song((err, song) => { 
   // Do stuff
});
```

You may want to read more about using Promise/async-await instead of callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
functions.random_song = () => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync('auto_playlist.txt', 'utf8');
  let songs = data.split('\n');
  songs.splice(-1, 1);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*songs.length);
  let rand_song = (songs[random]);
  return rand_song;
}

console.log(functions.random_song())
```

got it working, thanks for the help <3

Comment: Hey, this is `synchronous` way of reading the file, Your program will pause while reading the file. And if the file is big then the delay might be significant. Use Promise or callback approach.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code which use Promise to handle file read and data processing task asynchronously

```html
const fs = require('fs')
const functions = {}
functions.random_song = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('auto_playlist.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
            }
            let songs = data.split('\n');
            songs.splice(-1, 1);
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*songs.length);
            let random_song = (songs[random]);
            resolve(random_song);
        })
    })
}

functions.random_song()
.then(song => console.log('Song Name', song))
.catch(err => console.error('Error fetching songs', err))

console.log('It will be executed before promise is resolved')
```

Answer (score -1):

`fs.readFile` is asynchronus and your function will return before the file is read. Use `fs.readFileSync` [instead](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). Like this:

```
functions.random_song = () => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync('auto_playlist.txt', 'utf8');
    let songs = data.split('\n');
    songs.splice(-1, 1);
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*songs.length);
    let random_song = (songs[random]);
    return random_song;
}
```